# Can I remove the title/border of an app in Rally?

Tags: rally, code-rally

I recently found that one of the custom apps I can add to my Rally homepage is a custom HTML app.

This will be really useful to me, since I can use some HTML (Bootstrap) headers to separate apps on my page and make it more organized.

I got the custom HTML to show properly (and I currently have a header/divider) however, it is showing the grey title bar just like any other app would.

Is it possible to hide this when using the HTML app, so just the HTML output shows?

(If anyone is familiar with apps in Sharepoint, it's called a "Chrome" and you can hide the chrome/title so just the content shows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any built-in chrome to the apps themselves... Can you show a screenshot?  Are you following the general formula to embedding apps presented in this guide?

https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/embedding_apps